# "docker container rm <CONTAINER-ID>" vs "docker rm <CONTAINER-ID>"

Tags: docker

I had an issue removing a Docker container - it didn't work when I used the former command (Docker reported the container ID, but didn't remove it). The latter worked, though. The Docker syntax is the same though, as far as I can tell:

```
C:\Users\user>docker rm
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers

C:\Users\user>docker container rm
"docker container rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker container rm --help'.

Usage:  docker container rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers

C:\Users\user>
```

Comment: `docker container rm` and `docker rm` are identical.

Comment: If the container is running you can just use `docker -rm [containerid] -f` since it will force it to close.

Answer (score 0):

By using `docker rm` you can remove containers but it is also more generic and can be used to remove containers, volumes and links.

By contrast, `docker container rm <>` is *specific* to the removal of containers.